# Determine when value will be greater than x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want every time to add '$(b-x)$' to the value of $a$ and i want to know how many times i will repeat this operation to be the value of $a$ greater or equal to $x$.

$a = b+a - x$

I know that $b > x$ and $ a < x $

Any ideas?

Comment: your first equation says $x=b$. I think there is some error with your problem

Comment: Please check your equation as $a=b+a-x \Leftrightarrow x=b$.

Comment: $$a=b+a-x$$
$$a-b=a-x$$

So $a\ge x$ iff $a-x=a-b\ge0$.

Comment: edited, thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an arithmetic sequence

$t_n = a + n(b - x)$, (Starting at $n = 0$).

where $a < x < b$, and you want to know the first time that $t_n > x$

\begin{align}
   t_n & > x\\
   a + n(b - x) & > x\\
   n(b - x) & > x - a\\
   n & > \dfrac{x - a}{b - x}\\
   n & = \left \lceil \dfrac{x - a}{b - x} \right \rceil
\end{align}

If $\dfrac{x - a}{b - x}$ is not an integer, then
$n = \left \lfloor 1 + \dfrac{x - a}{b - x} \right \rfloor
   = \left \lfloor \dfrac{b - a}{b - x} \right \rfloor$

But if $\dfrac{x - a}{b - x}$ is an integer, then the answer is still 
$\left \lceil \dfrac{x - a}{b - x} \right \rceil$.

Comment: I think the correct answer is floor(x-a/b-x). Just check it with x = 1, a = 1000, b = 1010. My answer gives 100 steps but your gives 101 steps. I checked with python and the correct answer is 100 steps. Maybe you are counting the first term also?

Comment: @Kartik But you said a < x. That makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a = 1 and x = 1000, b = 1010. It gives 100 steps.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/boGvM.png

Comment: @Kartik I see the problem. I am starting with i = 1 and you are starting with i = 0. I will change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let the answer is n. Then you have to add $(b-x)$ to $a$, *n times*. So
$$x \geq a + n(b-x)$$
And then $$n=\frac{x-a}{b-x}$$
which is the answer.

If the answer comes in fractions then just take the next integer.